# Are there any standalone HTML markup validation tools

Tags: html, markup

Other than submit individual web pages for verification on the W3C site, are there any standalone tools that will do this job.

Ideally this would be a visual studio plugin that could catch errors at design time but one that would just take a wep application url running locally would be good.

Open source suggestions would be preferable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The W3C Markup Validator is an open source tool, which you can [download](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/validator/) and use it offline.

On Fedora, do:

```
yum install w3c-markup-validator
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the FireFox plugin "[HTMLTidy](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/)" to do this. When you are testing, you can point Firefox to your dev server (i.e. "http://localhost:52457/...") and it will work as if the site were live.

Also consider setting HTML errors to be raised as compile errors in VS and set your compatibility level/Doctype to XHTML 1.1 Strict to get them all. These settings are under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation

Answer (score 1):

you could try with [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[CSE HTML Validator](http://www.htmlvalidator.com/) is one I have used in the past.

It is not open source, but there is a free version.