# Is it possible to Validate ASP.NET pages as valid HTML before compile

Tags: asp.net, html, standards

Following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773070/are-there-any-standalone-html-markup-validation-tools) I run the suggested Tidy Program which came back with a whole load of errors regarding the tool not recognising ASP tags. Is it possible for a tool to validate ASP.NET pages before compile/delivery via a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using VS then your pages are being evaluated as you type them, mismatched tags, etc are highlighted. Beyond making sure that you have entered the HTML correctly I'm not sure what problem you are looking to solve.

My approach to any problem of this type is to solve it at source rather than patching mid-way.

Answer (score 0):

you could potentially perform your own validation by overriding the appropriate render methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the rendered ASP.NET (and with IIS7 even static) pages using a HttpModule. For a complete example check: [XHTML Validator For All](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/XHTML_Validator_For_All.aspx).

If you log the validation errors, you can later address them directly (at the source level).